# How to detect an android device whether it support USB Audio?

Tags: android, usb

Here is the official documentation about USB Audio https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb.html#usbAudio,
As we know Android system already supported USB Audio since version 4.0,but some mobile phone manufacturers disable the USB Audio feature,such as Huawei,Lenovo etc. 
USB Audio feature is very very important to my app,does anyone know any method to detect an android device whether support USB Audio feature or not?
Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: I have the same problem here. My app also needs an external USB audio device and I could not find any way to detect it (in the manifest for example). The only thing I can do is to inform the customer that his device does not support USB audio through AudioManager and AudioDevice functions. This is far to be acceptable, but this is the only thing I found...